# php- upload imagem e enviar para a base de dados

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou a tentar inserir uma imagem na base de dados mas quando clico upload imagem, da o seguinte erro: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/unn_w17015779/public_html/upload.php on line 9 File is not an image.;

Código HTML:

```
<body>
<?php include 'addDataAdmin.php';?>
<form name="ContactForm" action="addDataAdmin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
    ISBN:<input type="text" name="ISBN">
    Author's Name:<input type="text" name="Authorsname">
    Title:<input type="text" name="Title">
    Edition:<input type="number" name="edition" >
    Year:<input type="text" name="year" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" >

    Category:
    <select name="category" size="1">
        <option value="computing">Computing</option>
        <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
        <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
        <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
    </select>
    <br />

    Publisher:<input type="text" name="publisher">
    Quantity-in-stock:<input type="number" name="quantityinstock" >
    Price:<input type="text" name="price" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" formaction="/upload.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

código PHP:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) {

 $Image =$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Image']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO books (Image) VALUES('$Image')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
     {
        echo '<h3><font color="red">You have successfully updated </font></h3>';

        }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error';
                echo $sql;
            }
        }




?>;
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Que erro está dando? Edite a pergunta e coloque-o também. Talvez seja interessante colocar o formulário HTML inteiro também, pois no PHP você está tentando salvar um valor `$_POST["Image"]` que não está no código apresentado.

Comment: tem razão inicialmente pensei que o erro fosse na query, mas agora vejo que o problema é esse, a variavel $image não esta na form!

Comment: afinal n sei se será isso. quando eu clico em upload image. aparece isto:Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/unn_w17015779/public_html/upload.php on line 9
File is not an image.;

Comment: Sei que quer em PHP, mas dá uma olhada neste exemplo, que usa PHP também:https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu codigo funciona (com a observação de que no meu ambiente não havia execução das funções em javascript, pois você não as colocou). Com o formulario que você postou:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicando em Upload image:

File is an image - image/png.

Sugiro que você chame seu arquivo upload.php com esse pequeno trecho de codigo (o var_dump vai mostrar se realmente a uma imagem no array files):

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

Salvar na base de dados
O codigo escrito deve estar salvando alguma coisa, menos a imagem que você quer. Use a função file_get_contents para obter o conteudo da imagem do upload.

```
if (!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) {
    $Image =$conn->real_escape_string(
    file_get_contents($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]));
    $sql="INSERT INTO books (Image) VALUES('$Image')";
```

Isso deve permitir que sua imagem seja salva. Mas lembrando o array `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` deve apontar para um arquivo existente em algum lugar no seu computador.

Juntando tudo

Não há erros no seu script. Juntando tudo o que você postou e criando um banco de dados de teste, executei e funcionou (inseriu a imagem no banco). Veja os comentarios:

```
<?php

//minha conexao com o banco (você já tem isso)
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'aprendendo', '', 'aprendendo');

//só para depuração
var_dump ( $_FILES );

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["name"] );
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo ( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset ( $_POST ["submit"] )) {
    $check = getimagesize ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"] );
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check ["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (! empty ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["name"] )) {
    //obtem o conteudo da imagem com file_get_contents
    $Image = $conn->real_escape_string ( file_get_contents ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"]));
    //criei uma tabela ficticia chamada a, e uma coluna 
    //chamada b (iamgem), substitua pela sua
    $sql = "INSERT INTO a (b) VALUES('$Image')";
    if (mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql )) {
        echo '<h3><font color="red">You have successfully updated </font></h3>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
        //se ocorrer algum erro de sintaxe o sql será mostrado na tela
        echo $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: o meu codigo tambem funciona no que toca a upload, mas depois tem de ser armazenado na base de dados e acho que é o trecho da query que faz com que dê erro. seu trecho n me permite inserir na base de dados

Comment: No corpo da pergunta falava de um erro que você estava tendo na linha 9 (alvo da primeira resposta). Você já o corrigiu? De qualquer forma editei a resposta para incluir a parte de salvar a imagem. Atente para  fato de que a  parte anterior deve estar funcionando para que a segunda funcione.

Comment: o primeiro código que voce posto ou inicialmente usei-o apenas assim e não deu erro ai quando eu tentei inserir parte que iria enviar os dados para a base de dados é que deu erro

Comment: Qual foi o erro que deu?

Comment: Por favor veja o que esta escrito editei o post e coloquei o erro que da

Comment: Parece que a pergunta não foi atualizada, não tem o erro que voce disse que colocou.

Comment: "Estou a tentar inserir uma imagem na base de dados mas quando clico upload imagem, da o seguinte erro: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/unn_w17015779/public_html/upload.php on line 9 File is not an image.;"

Comment: oi Juven_v tentei usar o seu código mas aparece o seguinte erro: array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_5054.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpmdeTn3" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(7171642) } } File is an image - image/jpeg.;

Comment: Isso não é um erro. É apenas a saida da função var_dump (que mostra o conteudo de uma variavels). Com isso podemos ver que onde sua imagem está armazenada (tmp_name) e que suas validações estão funcionando (o if com a variavel check).

Comment: obrigado Juven_v por ter respondido tao rapido, estou um pouco perdida, tem como voce por favor explicar como faço para isto deixar de aparecer sff?

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta. Deve ter um pequeno erro de sintaxe no seu sql (nome de coluna escrito errado, etc). A edição tem as informações necessarias para resolver.

Comment: oi Juven_v de novo, afinal não esta funcionando, tou tendo o seguinte erro:array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_5046.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpooKK6j" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(6081742) } } File is an image - image/jpeg.ErrorColumn count doesn't match value count at row 1;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57573/discussion-between-diana-madeira-and-juven-v).

Answer (score 0):

Segue meus exemplos abaixo :

**upload_imagem.php**

```html
 <h1> Carregar a foto</h1>
<form method="POST" action="proc_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Imagem: <input name="arquivo" type="file"><br><br>
 
 <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
```

**proc_upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    </body>
        <?php
            include_once("conexao.php");
            $arquivo    = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

            //Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
            $_UP['pasta'] = 'foto/';

            //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
            $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5mb

            //Array com a extensões permitidas
            $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

            //Renomeiar
            $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

            //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
            $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
            $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite do PHP';
            $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado no HTML';
            $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
            $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

            //Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Sem sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
            if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
                die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
                exit; //Para a execução do script
            }

            //Faz a verificação da extensao do arquivo
            $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
            if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){        
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"A imagem não foi cadastrada extesão inválida.\");
                    </script>
                ";
            }

            //Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
            else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']){
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Arquivo muito grande.\");
                    </script>
                ";
            }

            //O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar move-lo para a pasta foto
            else{
                //Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
                if($UP['renomeia'] == true){
                    //Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
                    $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
                }else{
                    //mantem o nome original do arquivo
                    $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
                }
                //Verificar se é possivel mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta']. $nome_final)){
                    //Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO usuarios (
                    nome_imagem) VALUES('$nome_final')");
                    echo "
                        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Imagem cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                        </script>
                    ";  
                }else{
                    //Upload não efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                    echo "
                        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Imagem não foi cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                        </script>
                    ";
                }
            }


        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Altere no **proc_upload.php** a linhas que contem `<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/teste/upload_imagem.php'>` para o seu URL, isso tem que ser feito, se não , não irar funcionar

**conexao.php**

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "info";

    //Criar a conexão
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
    }
?>
```

Faça o teste com esses 3 arquivo em uma pasta Teste/ , com chmod 777